# Different placeholders on different browsers

Tags: html, date, input, salesforce, lwc

I have a quesion, I'm looking for documentation from Firefox and Chrome which tells me why on Chrome browser the input with type date looks like below

[image]

And on the firefox looks like this

[image]

Answer (score 0):

it's depend of browser version.
[image]

Comment: yeah i know, but I'm looking for documentation about this

Answer (score 0):

It would help if you would paste a sample of your code and css.
I'm guessing that you have some sort of property in css(something like -webkit-appearance: none;)